# Objective C block code

Tags: objective-c

I am fairy new to Objective C and am having the following dilemma. I want a piece of code to run after a method in the class prediction finishes running.

```
-(void)populate: (void (^)())completionHandler{//method that should run first
    //code that runs first
}
```

I call this method in the main function

```
[prediction populate:^{
    NSLog(@"it works")//it works is new displayed
}];
```

I expect "it works" to be displayed right after the populate method finishes running. But this doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just adding a `completionHandler` parameter to your method won't automatically run it.  You need to call it yourself when you're done with whatever you need to do in your `populate:` method:

```
-(void)populate: (void (^)())completionHandler { //method that should run first
    //code that runs first

    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler();
    }
}
```